# Experiencing "ApiError(406, 'Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json]" problem

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, opensearch

My elasticsearch version: 8.8.0
My elasticsearch-py version: 8.8.0

I tried to send file from AWS S3 to opensearch and have experienced the "ApiError(406, 'Content-Type header [application/vnd.elasticsearch+json])" error when calling `opensearch_client.index`.

Have already tried adding `headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` but it's not working.

The file has valid json format.
Does anyone know how to solve this?